# HttpServletResponse.sendError() does not redirect to error page

Tags: java, servlets

I have the following code in doFilter() method, where I get application scoped bean.

```
    if (request.getServletContext().getAttribute("resource")==null) {
        response.sendError(503);
        return;
    }
```

I mapped 503 code to specific error page in web.xml. And I really get content of error page in browser, if error occurs. But the address in address bar doesn't change for error page address: an address of requested servlet leaves there. Is it right behaviour? I'd like to inform explicitly about redirection to error page.
Is it only possible with sendRedirect()?

Comment: Why do you want to change the URL? Why do you want your error pages to be publicly accessible? The canonical approach is to keep them in `/WEB-INF` folder and let the container forward to it. Redirecting would only completely break the status code and mislead the browsers and searchbots about the happening by returning a 3nn/2nn. Just do **not** redirect to the error page!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. When you use sendError() it will respond to the current request with an error page. If you instead want the URL to change to the error page URL, you will need to use sendRedirect() to respond with a redirect.