# How to rethrow exception as @ResponseStatus-annotated exception in Spring @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have made exception, that I'm throwing always when I want a 404 page:

```
@ResponseStatus( value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND )
public class PageNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
```

I want to create controller-wide `@ExceptionHandler` that will re-throw `ArticleNotFoundException`(which causes error 500) as my 404 exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler( value=ArticleNotFoundException.class )
public void handleArticleNotFound() {
    throw new PageNotFoundException();
}
```

But it doesn't work - I still have **error 500** and Spring logs:

`ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: ...`

Note that I translate code to html so response cannot be empty or simple String like with `ResponseEntity`. `web.xml` entry:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/resources/error-pages/404.html</location>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
</error-page>
```

**FINAL SOLUTION FROM ANSWER COMMENTS**

It's not a full re-throw, but at least it uses `web.xml` error page mapping like my `PageNotFoundException`

```
    @ExceptionHandler( value = ArticleNotFoundException.class )
    public void handle( HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND );

    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of throwing an exception try this:

```
@ExceptionHandler( value=ArticleNotFoundException.class )
public ResponseEntity<String> handleArticleNotFound() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

This will basically return a Spring object that gets converted into a 404 by your controller.

You can pass it a different HttpStatus if you want to return different HTTP status messages to your front-end.

If you are deadset on doing this with annotations, just annotate that controller method with @ResponseStatus and don't throw an exception.

Basically if you annotate a method with `@ExceptionHandler` I'm 90% sure that Spring expects that method to consume that exception and not throw another one. By throwing a different exception, Spring thinks that the exception wasn't handled and that your exception handler failed, hence the message in your logs

EDIT:

To get it to return to a specific page try

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(location/of/your/page.html, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

EDIT 2:
You should be able to do this:

```
@ExceptionHandler( value=ArticleNotFoundException.class )
public ResponseEntity<String> handleArticleNotFound(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendRedirect(location/of/your/page);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but this works as `404` code but **sends empty response**. This is different than behaviour with my `PageNotFoundException` - which is translated to .html file by web.xml `<error-page>`

Comment: unfortunatelly, it takes that path string as response body, just displaying it on a page.

Comment: It worked with returning `String` with path and annotated by ` @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` but formaly, this is not quite a response to my question - no re-throw occured but simple duplicated, decentralized code. I will wait more and If no one respond I will accept and update notice.

Comment: No worries, I was wrestling with something very similar myself 2 weeks ago. Good luck

Comment: Just found this, have a read. This will let you use @ExceptionHandler and redirect off to your error page.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318583/httpservletresponse-senderror-does-not-redirect-to-error-page

Comment: This is awesome. I was really stuck to find a solution returning response DTOs, and I couldn't see that I could simply return a response entity. Thank you!

Comment: Or use the build `ResponseEntity.notFound().build();`