# Throw exception inside @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When i throws exception `throw new ForbiddenAjaxException()` inside `@ExceptionHandler`

```
  @ExceptionHandler({ ForbiddenException.class })
  public String forbiddenException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {

        if( "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With")) ){
            throw new ForbiddenAjaxException();
        }

        return "redirect:/projects/error";
  }
```

It did not respond with `@ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN )`

```
@ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN )
public class ForbiddenAjaxException extends RuntimeException  {}
```

Log error :

```
11:00:06.277 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public java.lang.String controller.projects.ExceptionHandling.forbiddenException(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
exceptions.ForbiddenAjaxException
    at controller.projects.ExceptionHandling.forbiddenException(ExceptionHandling.java:33) ~[classes/:?]
```

P.S : When `ForbiddenException` (normal requests not ajax ones) is thrown it get caught by the exception handler.

Comment: what happen if you throw the `ForbiddenAjaxException` directly from the controller?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077573/how-to-rethrow-exception-as-responsestatus-annotated-exception-in-spring-excep

Comment: @Ralph it works if I throw the ForbiddenAjaxException directly from the controller

Comment: Can you add the complete code for Exception handler and Controller code ?

Comment: what happens when you remove @ExceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
  @ExceptionHandler({ ForbiddenException.class })
  public Object forbiddenException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {

        if( "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With")) ){
             return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }

        return "redirect:/projects/error";
  }
```